# How to deal with long lines in .gitconfig?

Tags: git

In my `.gitconfig` I have this:

```
[format]
    pretty = "%C(bold blue)%h %C(bold green)%<|(20)% \
ar%C(reset) %C(white)% s %C(dim white) -% an%C(reset) \
%C(bold yellow)% d \
%C(bold red)% N"
```

Notice that the three last lines cannot be indented otherwise I would get unwanted indentation in the format string.

Is there a more elegant way to write this such as this (which of course doesn't work):

```
[format]
    pretty = "%C(bold blue)%h %C(bold green)%<|(20)%" +
             "ar%C(reset) %C(white)% s %C(dim white) -% an%C(reset)" +
             "%C(bold yellow)% d " +
             "%C(bold red)% N"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it inside a bash script and there you can use a string to achive what you want.

for example:

#### `~/.githelper`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

HASH="%C(yellow)%h%Creset"
RELATIVE_TIME="%Cgreen(%ar)%Creset"
AUTHOR="%C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset"
REFS="%C(red)%d%Creset"
SUBJECT="%s"

FORMAT="$HASH}$RELATIVE_TIME}$AUTHOR}$REFS $SUBJECT"

show_git_head() {
  pretty_git_log -1
  git show -p --pretty="tformat:"
}

pretty_git_log() {
  git log --graph --abbrev-commit --date=relative --  pretty="tformat:${FORMAT}" $* |
  # Repalce (2 years ago) with (2 years)
  sed -Ee 's/(^[^<]*) ago)/\1)/' |
  # Replace (2 years, 5 months) with (2 years)
  sed -Ee 's/(^[^<]*), [[:digit:]]+ .*months?)/\1)/' |
  # Line columns up based on } delimiter
  column -s '}' -t |
  # Page only if we need to
  less -FXRS
}
```

than your alias will use this script like this for example:

```
l = "!source ~/.githelper && pretty_git_log"
```